# Prisma Studio error when creating a one-to-one relationship in postgreSQL db

Tags: postgresql, next.js, orm, prisma

I am working through the Next.Js fullstack app tutorial [here](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres). It's excellent and awesome, but I am stuck on an error in the Prisma Studio GUI when I try to create tables in my postgreSQL db hosted on Supabase.

Error in full:

```
Type: undefined
Message: 
Invalid `prisma.visitor.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    id: 545,
    ~~
    countryCode: 'dasd',
    regionName: 'dads',
    city: 'dasd',
    ipAddress: 'dasda',
    count: {
      connect: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  },
  select: {
    id: true,
    countryCode: true,
    regionName: true,
    city: true,
    ipAddress: true,
    count: true,
    countId: true
  }
}

Unknown arg `id` in data.id for type VisitorCreateInput. Available args:

type VisitorCreateInput {
  countryCode?: String | Null
  regionName?: String | Null
  city?: String | Null
  ipAddress?: String | Null
  count: CountCreateNestedOneWithoutVisitorInput
}
```

Is it the double tildes after the id? The visitor table connects to the Count table just fine when I look up the Count entry in the popup section, but it seems to be an issue with the Visitor table itself. I am using VScode to type up my data models, and am using the Prisma extension with no errors showing. Any help would be appreciated!

I haven't really tried much, because to me the error doesn't make sense, and Google isn't really helping.

EDIT: forgot to show the data models:

```
model Count {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  addOne  Int      @map("add_one")
  visitor Visitor?
}

model Visitor {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  countryCode String? @map("country_code")
  regionName  String? @map("region_name")
  city        String?
  ipAddress   String? @map("ip_address")
  count       Count   @relation(fields: [countId], references: [id])
  countId     Int     @unique
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with the create function in Prisma autogenerating an ID, so I'm going to continue with the tutorial and see if I can fix the error by not having it be an issue, as I'm not typing ID's when I create an entry in the front end.